# Secured social doesn't redirect correctly with NGINX in play framework

Tags: nginx

After successful login, securedsocial redirect to the URL http://sss/ instead of http://ip:9009. The proxy_pass works fine except when logging to the system with securedsocial.Any fix to this?

NGIXIN.conf

```
 upstream sss { 
     server ip:9009; 
 }
```

SecuredSocial.conf

```
 onLoginGoTo=/


worker_processes  auto;
events {
   worker_connections  20000;
}


http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;
sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;

upstream playserver {
    server 127.0.0.1:9009;
  }

server {
    listen  80;
    server_name  localhost;

        access_log off;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://playserver;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: Show full nginx config

Comment: just posted the full config

Comment: add `proxy_add_header Host $host;`

Comment: works like a charm only i needed to change "add" to "set"            proxy_set_header Host $host;